# How to deal with the "missing right parenthesis " in Oracle 19c?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have written a piece of code in Oracle database 19c to extract the salary of employees who earns more than the average salary of their respective departments but the query shows "missing right parenthesis". Can anybody help me with it, like where and what the error is all about?

```
select ename 
from emp 
where sal > (select round(avg(sal)) as avg_sal, deptno 
             from  emp 
             group by deptno 
             order by 2);
```

Comment: You need a correlated subquery. This one will return a buncgh of average salaries, one for each department.

Comment: Oracle wants column names in the GROUP BY, not ordinal positions.

Comment: You should rewrite your query. What do you means by query ` WHERE sal > (avgsal, deptno)` ? Use CTE and join instead to compare only one - to - one column.

Comment: How is it possible that a column (sal) be greater than 2 columns?!

Answer (score 1):

You can use these queries to get job done.

```sql
select ename 
from emp e1 
where sal > (select round(avg(sal)) as avg_sal
             from  emp e2
             where e2.deptno = e1.deptno 
             );
```

or

```
select e1.ename 
from emp e1,
  (
  select round(avg(sal)) as avg_sal, deptno 
  from  emp 
  group by deptno
  ) e2
where e1.deptno = e2.deptno
and e1.sal > avg_sal
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Now the output of your subquery is 2 columns and multiple rows, which is against the business logic you described.
To gain the desired result you need to modify the query a bit:

- remove the second column in subquery;
- remove `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses from the subquery.

Should be as follows:

```
SELECT ename FROM emp WHERE sal > (SELECT round(AVG(sal)) AS avg_sal FROM emp);
```

Now subquery returns only one values which is valuated with each salary in the main query and returns employees' names of ones, that have salary more that average.

Comment: A correlated subquery is needed. ("more than the average salary of their respective departments")

Comment: Ups, I misread the question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The "missing right parenthesis" error is that the `ORDER BY` clause is not allowed in the sub-query so the SQL parser expects the query to end after the `GROUP BY` clause.

Once you fix that you get a further error that the sub-query will return multiple rows:

```sql
select ename 
from   emp 
where  sal > (select round(avg(sal)) as avg_sal, deptno 
              from  emp 
              group by deptno);
```

Outputs a different error message:

> ```
> ORA-00913: too many values
> ```

To fix that you need to restrict the sub-query to a single row and correlate the outer-query to the sub-query:

```sql
select ename 
from   emp e
where  sal > (select round(avg(sal)) as avg_sal
              from  emp a
              WHERE e.deptno = a.deptno);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE emp (ename, sal, deptno) AS
SELECT 'Alice', 100, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Beryl', 200, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Carol', 300, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Debra', 100, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Ester', 200, 2 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | ENAME |
> | --- |
> | Carol |
> | Ester |

---

If you want to do it in a single table-scan then you can use analytic functions:

```sql
SELECT ename
FROM   (
  SELECT ename,
         sal,
         ROUND(AVG(sal) OVER (PARTITION BY deptno)) AS avg_sal
  FROM   emp
)
WHERE  sal > avg_sal;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=87d999a76f34b182b0e7afbaedf3f003)*